# How to transfer data from Windows to Mac using USB

Tags: windows, macos, mac, usb, format

**What is happening:**

I have a PC running Windows 8.1 and a Mac running Mac OS X 10.6.2. I also have a USB which is 8GB. My Mac isn't connected to the internet but my PC is. When I connect my USB to my Windows Machine it works as usual. It shows it's formatted as FAT32. However when I insert it to my Mac it doesn't show as a device but in Disk Utility it shows that it isn't mounted:[image: Disk Utility]

---

When I try to mount the drive it says that I need to run First Aid on it. But nothing different happens.

I was wandering if there was a way to open Mac OS extended/HFS/HFS+ USBs on Windows. This is the only way my Mac reads it.

Comment: What about using DropBox/Google Drive/Live?  You could copy the files there and copy to your Mac or vice versa.

Comment: Try plugging the USB disk in and rebooting your Mac... does the disk get mounted this way?

Comment: I can use any of what  you recommended because I also stated that I haven't connected my Mac to the internet

Comment: I will try doing that "rebooting your Mac..."

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Format it as FAT on your Mac then use it on your Windows machine.

Comment: I agree with @qasdfdsaq. Something is probably slightly corrupted in this drive's MBR or FAT32 volume headers, and Windows is taking it in stride but OS X isn't. Reformat it as FAT32 on the Mac and the Mac will work with it fine.

Comment: Is it possible it's in ExFAT (aka FAT64) format, and Windows is misreporting it? IIRC ExFAT support was added to OS X in version 10.6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It turns out I was booting into safe boot by accident. I booted into normal mode and it worked. Although I had to do what qasdfdsaq said.